# CMake: FIXUP_BUNDLE creating empty frameworks on OS X

Tags: macos, frameworks, cmake, bundle

I am trying to use the CMake function FIXUP_BUNDLE to fix up an application bundle, but am getting install-time warnings and for lack of better terminology, not a fixed-up bundle.

The installed bundle has the right structure, but the frameworks it uses aren't correctly copied in.  Only each framework's directory structure is copied in and not the actual shared library binary.  For example, my bundle uses SFML 2.0's System framework.  Note that all SFML frameworks I use are stored in `/Library/Frameworks`.  Here is what I get in `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/` with respect to this SFML component:

```
sfml-system.framework/
    Versions/
        2.0.0/
```

And that's all I get, just the directories.  The actual SFML System framework has a structure like this:

```
sfml-system.framework/
    Resources  (this is a symlink)
    sfml-system  (this is a symlink)
    Versions/
        2.0.0/
            Resources/
                Info.plist
            sfml-system  (this is the actual library binary)
        Current  (this is a symlink)
```

In my project, executables all have the same format so I have a small function to add them using this common format.  The function just adds the executable, sets the libraries to link against, and at install time, installs the application bundle and calls FIXUP_BUNDLE on it.  Here is that function:

```
FUNCTION(ADD_CUSTOM_EXECUTABLE TARGET HEADERS SOURCES DEPENDENCIES)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${TARGET} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${ARGN})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${TARGET} ${DEPENDENCIES})

    INSTALL(TARGETS ${TARGET} BUNDLE DESTINATION .)

    INSTALL(CODE "
        INCLUDE(BundleUtilities)
        FIXUP_BUNDLE(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${TARGET}.app \"\" \"\") 
    ")
ENDFUNCTION(ADD_CUSTOM_EXECUTABLE)
```

I don't pass in anything for the LIBS or DIRS parameters of FIXUP_BUNDLE because I am currently not using any plugins.  The ALL_BUILD project builds fine in Xcode, and the install project runs without failing, but produces many warnings like this for each library discovered via `otool -L`.  Here's an example showing the start of the warnings for SFML's System framework, almost immediately after FIXUP_BUNDLE is called:

```
fixup_bundle
    app='/Users/user/Desktop/SFML_Testing_BUILD/dist/MyApp.app'
    libs=''
    dirs=''
fixup_bundle: preparing...
warning: embedded item does not exist 'Users/user/Desktop/SFML_Testing_BUILD/
dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.0.0/
sfml-system'
warning: cannot resolve item '@executable_path/../Frameworks/
sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.0.0/sfml-system'

possible problems:
    need more directories?
    need to use InstallRequiredSystemLibraries?
    run in install tree instead of build tree?
```

And a short bit later, stuff like this:

```
warning: target '@executable_path/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/
2.0.0/sfml-system' is not absolute...
warning: target '@executable_path/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/
2.0.0/sfml-system' does not exist...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/
usr/bin/otool: can't open file: @executable_path/../Frameworks/
sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.0.0/sfml-system (No such file or directory)
otool: can't open file: @executable_path/../Frameworks/
sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.0.0/sfml-system
(No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?  I scoured the internet for a solution, but had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If the Framework you are trying to pull in is in "/Library/Frameworks" then it is assumed to be a "system library" which does not actually need to be pulled in... The assumption is that if you depend on an installed system library (rather than one you've built yourself somewhere), then your end users will also have the same installed system library. (You would have to require them to install SFML prior to installing your app.)

We do this on purpose to discourage people from accidentally including system frameworks in their bundles that they are not legally supposed to include. Whether it's legal for you to bundle up the SFML frameworks is a burden that is strictly on you.

If this assumption is wrong in your case, and you want the SFML stuff to be considered "non-system," you may have to customize BundleUtilities to handle it.

It would be easier to try this first, though: write a script that copies them into your build tree bundle first, and then install the bundle, and see if fixup_bundle works on that prior to attempting the following custom overrides.

If necessary, you can attempt to customize as follows:

First, change your install(CODE snippet with inline code to an install(SCRIPT call that calls a configured/generated script file. Otherwise, there will be too much code to put in that block, and all the escaping will get nasty.

Next, before including BundleUtilities in your script, add an override function for the GetPrerequisites gp_resolved_file_type function. That's what BundleUtilities uses to declare whether or not a library is a "system" library. Your override function, named gp_resolved_file_type_override will be called for every file type resolution that BundleUtilities needs. You may be able write it to simply match the library name to the string "sfml", and if it matches, then declare the type to be "other", and your declaration will win.

After that, some of the above warnings should go away, but you may then encounter other problems that require further customization.

It's a bit nasty and complicated, but should be doable with existing CMake...

However:

The fact that BundleUtilities pulls in anything at all for a system library is a mistake, and that should be reported as a bug in the CMake bug tracker: http://www.cmake.org/Bug